# image : None while successfully upload Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting image url `None` while successfully uploading the image, i expected to get the image url which i sent to my server, but i'm getting the `None` value instead. 
 Any help, would be much appreciated. thank you so much in advance.

serializers.py

```
class BulkImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    image1 = ImageField(required=True)
    image2 = ImageField(required=False)
    user_id = CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BulkImage
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        image1 = validated_data['image1']
        image2 = validated_data['image2']
        validated_data['user_id'] = User.objects.get(email=self.context['request'].user.email)
        img_obj = BulkImage.objects.create(
                image1 = image1,
                image2 = image2 if image2 else None,
                user_id = validated_data['user_id']
            )
        return validated_data
```

views.py

```
class BulkImageAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        user = request.user
        data           = request.data
        serializer =  BulkImageSerializer(data=data, context = {'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({
                'message' : 'Image upload successfully',
                'data' : serializer.data,
                },status=200)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=400)
```

output:

```
{
    "message": "Image upload successfully",
    "data": {
        "image1": null,
        "image2": null,
        "user_id": "employee01gmailcom"
    },
}
```

Comment: Have you installed Pillow for the images??
`pip install Pillow`

Comment: yes @SuryaBista

Answer (score 0):

I use [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) maybe it work, I guess.

`serializers.py`

```py
class BulkImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BulkImage
        fields = "__all__"
```

`views.py`

```py
class BulkImageAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BulkImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BulkImageSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```